# .htaccess, skip a variable level

Tags: .htaccess

I am struggling with a .htaccess issue.

I have a url like `/files/download/1234/abc/def.pdf` where `/1234/` is a variable value and changes for each user.

However recently we transferred all the files to `/userdownload/abc/def.png`

How do i skip the variable level using my .htaccess file?

I tried stuff like:

```
^files/downloads/(.*)/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/userdownload/$2 [R=301,L]
```

However this did not give the result i needed as it also removed the /abc/ from the link.

Anyone knows how i can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^files/downloads/(\d+)/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/userdownload/$2 [R=301,L]
```

If your variable is only numeric.

Or you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^files/downloads/([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/userdownload/$2 [R=301,L]
```